# Count with Join in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this two table where it records what kind of food is the user's favorite:

`users` table

```
 ------------
 id | country
 ------------
 1  | US
 2  | PH
 3  | US
 4  | US
 5  | PH
```

`food_favourites` table

```
-----------------
food_id | user_id
-----------------
3       | 1
7       | 1
3       | 2
3       | 3
3       | 4
```

I want to know how many unique users from US tagged food_id 3 as their favorite.

So far I have this query:

```
select *, count(user_id) as total
from food_favourite
inner join users on users.id = food_favourites.user_id
where food_favourites.food_id = 3
and users.country = 'US'
group by users.id
```

Well This doesn't work coz it returns `total` to 4 instead of just 3.

I also tried doing subqueries - no luck, I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Here's a clue: '*' is never going to be part of the answer.

Comment: And what country is 'EU'?

Comment: My bad, For a minute I thought Europe is a country, shame on me...

Comment: Try to avoid using `*` in any of your SQL unless you're legitimately using every column of the table you're pulling back.  It makes more data have to be returned than what you likely need, and when this is dealing with large tables and/or large amounts of records, it can have a significant performance hit.

Comment: One thing that's messed up is your database: In `food_favourites`, you have two entries for `user_id = 1`, so what is the relation between those two tables? What are the guarantees concerning uniqueness? Suggestion: Create an MCVE first, then ask here!

Comment: I think there is no guarantee of uniqueness, thus the total results may exceed the actual user count.  This may very well be valid in some scenarios (at least that's my takeaway given the sample data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE users
(user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,country CHAR(2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES
(1,'US'),
(2,'EU'),
(3,'US'),
(4,'US'),
(5,'EU');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS favourite_foods;

CREATE TABLE favourite_foods
(food_id INT NOT NULL
,user_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(food_id,user_id)
);

INSERT INTO favourite_foods VALUES
(3,1),
(7,1),
(3,2),
(3,3),
(3,4);

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.user_id) distinct_users
  FROM users u 
  JOIN favourite_foods f 
    ON f.user_id = u.user_id 
 WHERE u.country = 'US'
   AND f.food_id = 3;
+----------------+
| distinct_users |
+----------------+
|              3 |
+----------------+
```

Comment: Oh my, I totally forgot about distinct! Thanks! This works. 

P.S. some fields are wrong like u.user_id... but not really a big deal since we both understand how it should be. :)

Comment: That's a table alias.  Basically a shortcut to prevent having to type out the full table name each time.

Comment: Actually, DISTINCT is redundant here as every combination of food and user MUST be unique, but it doesn't hurt to keep it in case you want to know distinct users who like burgers and/or pizza, say. I renamed the columns for clarity. I would advise that you do likewise.

Comment: In this example, the PK on favourite_foods means you can never have more than one record associating a user with a food, so DISTINCT is not strictly necessary here and you'll get the same result without it.

Comment: @PaulCampbell Erm, that's what I said.

Comment: Didn't see your comment before posting mine.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the answer to the above question should be 3 as id 1,3,4 all have food_id 3 as their favorite food.

To just print the query try this, it will surely work:

```
select count(*) as total from food_favourites 
inner join users on users.id=food_favourites.user_id 
where food_id=3 and country='US';
```

Comment: Hi, I think this will return 4, since this is not grouped by user_id and the data have two "1" user_id. And it seems that adding group by makes the result "1" or "2" coz it counts per group. Thanks for the help btw

Comment: It will definitely return 3

Comment: You're assuming that user/food combinations are unique - but I agree that this is a reasonable assumption

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know how many unique users from US tagged food_id 3 as their favorite.

You count unique values with `COUNT DISTINCT`:

```
select count(distinct ff.user_id) as total
from food_favourite ff
inner join users u on u.id = ff.user_id
where ff.food_id = 3
and u.country = 'US';
```

Don't group by user, because you don't want a result per user. You want one row with one number, telling you how many US users prefer food 3.

An alternative that I prefer over the join. The query reads like I would word the task: count users from US that like food 3.

```
select count(*) as total
from users
where country = 'US'
and id in (select user_id from food_favourites where food_id = 3);
```

No unnecessary join and hence no need to get back to distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select count(user_id) as total
from food_favourites
inner join users on users.id = food_favourites.user_id
where food_favourites.food_id = 3
   and users.country = 'US'
```

Comment: This will return 4 instead of just 2 because this is not grouped by user_id.

Comment: No, it will return a syntax error, like your original version, because 'table' is a keyword. Remove the word 'table' and it will return 3 records

Comment: Oh, sorry, I actually coded everything without table, it's just on my mind and I end up typing it here.

Answer (score 0):

The sub_query is

```
SELECT u.country, f.food_id,  COUNT(u.id) AS 'Total users'
FROM users u
INNER JOIN food_favourites AS f ON (u.id = f.[user_id])
WHERE u.country = 'US'
GROUP BY u.country, f.food_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(user_id) as total, Country
from food_favourites 
inner join users on users.id = food_favourites.user_id
where food_favourites.food_id = 3
and users.country = 'US'
group by country
```

Untested, but I think this is what you're after?  This will return results only for the US and a food id of 3.  If you want something more reusable that you can simply loop through the results for ALL countries...something like this should work (once again, untested...):

```
select count(user_id) as total, Country, food_id
from food_favourites 
inner join users on users.id = food_favourites.user_id
group by country, food_id
order by country, food_id
```

Comment: Hi, sorry but no. I'm trying to fetch the total of all users (unique) who tagged a certain food in food_favourites table who lives in 'US'.

Comment: I made some edits to this a moment ago which should now match what you're looking after.

Comment: Thanks for this, however Its just me but I find looping through the results kinda hackish? I wonder if this can be done via subqueries tho

Comment: Depends on what you're doing with the results.  Sometimes this is exactly what you'll want to do.  If you're trying to return one off results, the first of the two queries is the better way to go.  If you're trying to kick out a table with all of the data you have (some sort of  report, etc.) the second way is better.